# How to cantilever a roof beyond the end wall?

Tags: roof, engineering

How can this roof be extended 16 inches beyond the end wall?  Seems like it requires some 8 foot 2x4's but I'm unsure how to brace them to the truss.  My way of thinking would put them above 4 inner trusses and also above the outer truss, which seems wrong.

[image: How to extend this roof edge 16 inches beyond the end wall]

Would blocks provide enough support?

[image: 4x4 blocks]

Thanks to Sam's keywords (“step down truss” and “roof outriggers”) I was able to find this image showing a "lookout" and "fly rafter".

[image: lookout and fly rafter]

From there, I was able to come up with a reasonable solution:

[image]

Comment: Google “step down truss” and “roof outriggers”. You could use a step down truss or frame in a wall to allow outriggers.

Comment: have you noticed how every load bearing structure is composed of triangles? .... look at the second picture ... no triangles .... add diagonals from bottom left to top right

Comment: I think you need to consult a structural engineer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems more of an engineering question that requires expert advice from a certified professional.

Comment: Is there a different SE group I should be addressing?  I'm seeking that type of advice.

Comment: I don't think there is.  Mind you - It *is* a good question - but it's a very specific question that requires engineering expertise.  As such it's a bit too narrow for this site, where we focus on questions that a general contractor can authoritatively answer.  When you get down to structural engineering levels you need professional, certified advice.  Getting this wrong could result in SERIOUS consequences - like the structure collapsing - with someone under it.